# Why is "Find my friends" gone from Today Pane and how to get it back?

Tags: notifications, find-my-friends

For a long time I used the "Find my friends" widget in the Today pane of MacOS, but since last week it is gone and cannot be added again.  Find my Friends works as expected on iCloud.com and on iOS.  On this Macbook however, my today pane looks like below.  Can I reset the today pane or get Find My Friends back in some other way?

[image: Today pane without Find my Friends]

**Update**: The find my friends framework seems to be up and running. I can ask Siri for the location of a Friend and the widget is displayed in Siri's results with the location.  It really seems like some settings/preferences mess-up with Notification center.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open Finder and use <kbd>Cmd</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>G</kbd> to open the "Go to" dialog and enter the following path
`/System/Library/Frameworks/NotificationCenter.framework/PlugIns`

Repeat the step above for the following path
`/System/Library/Frameworks/NotificationCenter.framework/Versions/A/Resources`

You should have two directories that look something like this:
[image: Plugins]
[image: Resources]

Scroll to the bottom of the 'Resources' window and you'll find the "Widget Simulator"

[image: Widget Simulator]

Click on the "Find My Friends" icon and drag it onto the "Widget Simulator" icon, this should launch the Widget Simulator and run the Find My Friends widget inside.

[image: Drag and Drop]

Now check if the widget appears in Notification Centre.

### Update:

In terminal explore the contents of the Find my Friends widget, it should contain the following files

```
├── Info.plist
├── MacOS
│   └── com.apple.ncplugin.FindMyFriends
├── Resources
│   ├── AppIconMacWidget.icns
│   ├── Base.lproj
│   │   ├── FMFMacTodayViewController.nib
│   │   ├── FMFNoFriendsViewController.nib
│   │   ├── FMFNoiCloudViewController.nib
│   │   └── ListRowViewController.nib
│   ├── FMFAccountNotProvisionedViewController.nib
│   ├── ar.lproj
│   │   ├── FMFNoFriendsViewController.strings
│   │   ├── FMFNoiCloudViewController.strings
│   │   ├── InfoPlist.strings
│   │   ├── ListRowViewController.strings
│   │   └── Localizable.strings
│   ├── ca.lproj
│   │   ├── FMFNoFriendsViewController.strings
│   │   ├── FMFNoiCloudViewController.strings
│   │   ├── InfoPlist.strings
│   │   ├── ListRowViewController.strings
│   │   └── Localizable.strings
│   ├── cs.lproj
│   │   ├── FMFNoFriendsViewController.strings
│   │   ├── FMFNoiCloudViewController.strings
│   │   ├── InfoPlist.strings
│   │   ├── ListRowViewController.strings
│   │   └── Localizable.strings
│   ├── da.lproj
│   │   ├── FMFNoFriendsViewController.strings
│   │   ├── FMFNoiCloudViewController.strings
│   │   ├── InfoPlist.strings
│   │   ├── ListRowViewController.strings
│   │   └── Localizable.strings
│   ├── de.lproj
│   │   ├── FMFNoFriendsViewController.strings
│   │   ├── FMFNoiCloudViewController.strings
│   │   ├── InfoPlist.strings
│   │   ├── ListRowViewController.strings
│   │   └── Localizable.strings
│   ├── el.lproj
│   │   ├── FMFNoFriendsViewController.strings
│   │   ├── FMFNoiCloudViewController.strings
│   │   ├── InfoPlist.strings
│   │   ├── ListRowViewController.strings
│   │   └── Localizable.strings
│   ├── en.lproj
│   │   ├── InfoPlist.strings
│   │   └── Localizable.strings
│   ├── es.lproj
│   │   ├── FMFNoFriendsViewController.strings
│   │   ├── FMFNoiCloudViewController.strings
│   │   ├── InfoPlist.strings
│   │   ├── ListRowViewController.strings
│   │   └── Localizable.strings
│   ├── es_419.lproj
│   │   ├── FMFNoFriendsViewController.strings
│   │   ├── FMFNoiCloudViewController.strings
│   │   ├── InfoPlist.strings
│   │   ├── ListRowViewController.strings
│   │   └── Localizable.strings
│   ├── fi.lproj
│   │   ├── FMFNoFriendsViewController.strings
│   │   ├── FMFNoiCloudViewController.strings
│   │   ├── InfoPlist.strings
│   │   ├── ListRowViewController.strings
│   │   └── Localizable.strings
│   ├── fr.lproj
│   │   ├── FMFNoFriendsViewController.strings
│   │   ├── FMFNoiCloudViewController.strings
│   │   ├── InfoPlist.strings
│   │   ├── ListRowViewController.strings
│   │   └── Localizable.strings
│   ├── he.lproj
│   │   ├── FMFNoFriendsViewController.strings
│   │   ├── FMFNoiCloudViewController.strings
│   │   ├── InfoPlist.strings
│   │   ├── ListRowViewController.strings
│   │   └── Localizable.strings
│   ├── hr.lproj
│   │   ├── FMFNoFriendsViewController.strings
│   │   ├── FMFNoiCloudViewController.strings
│   │   ├── InfoPlist.strings
│   │   ├── ListRowViewController.strings
│   │   └── Localizable.strings
│   ├── hu.lproj
│   │   ├── FMFNoFriendsViewController.strings
│   │   ├── FMFNoiCloudViewController.strings
│   │   ├── InfoPlist.strings
│   │   ├── ListRowViewController.strings
│   │   └── Localizable.strings
│   ├── id.lproj
│   │   ├── FMFNoFriendsViewController.strings
│   │   ├── FMFNoiCloudViewController.strings
│   │   ├── InfoPlist.strings
│   │   ├── ListRowViewController.strings
│   │   └── Localizable.strings
│   ├── it.lproj
│   │   ├── FMFNoFriendsViewController.strings
│   │   ├── FMFNoiCloudViewController.strings
│   │   ├── InfoPlist.strings
│   │   ├── ListRowViewController.strings
│   │   └── Localizable.strings
│   ├── ja.lproj
│   │   ├── FMFNoFriendsViewController.strings
│   │   ├── FMFNoiCloudViewController.strings
│   │   ├── InfoPlist.strings
│   │   ├── ListRowViewController.strings
│   │   └── Localizable.strings
│   ├── ko.lproj
│   │   ├── FMFNoFriendsViewController.strings
│   │   ├── FMFNoiCloudViewController.strings
│   │   ├── InfoPlist.strings
│   │   ├── ListRowViewController.strings
│   │   └── Localizable.strings
│   ├── ms.lproj
│   │   ├── FMFNoFriendsViewController.strings
│   │   ├── FMFNoiCloudViewController.strings
│   │   ├── InfoPlist.strings
│   │   ├── ListRowViewController.strings
│   │   └── Localizable.strings
│   ├── nl.lproj
│   │   ├── FMFNoFriendsViewController.strings
│   │   ├── FMFNoiCloudViewController.strings
│   │   ├── InfoPlist.strings
│   │   ├── ListRowViewController.strings
│   │   └── Localizable.strings
│   ├── no.lproj
│   │   ├── FMFNoFriendsViewController.strings
│   │   ├── FMFNoiCloudViewController.strings
│   │   ├── InfoPlist.strings
│   │   ├── ListRowViewController.strings
│   │   └── Localizable.strings
│   ├── pl.lproj
│   │   ├── FMFNoFriendsViewController.strings
│   │   ├── FMFNoiCloudViewController.strings
│   │   ├── InfoPlist.strings
│   │   ├── ListRowViewController.strings
│   │   └── Localizable.strings
│   ├── pt.lproj
│   │   ├── FMFNoFriendsViewController.strings
│   │   ├── FMFNoiCloudViewController.strings
│   │   ├── InfoPlist.strings
│   │   ├── ListRowViewController.strings
│   │   └── Localizable.strings
│   ├── pt_PT.lproj
│   │   ├── FMFNoFriendsViewController.strings
│   │   ├── FMFNoiCloudViewController.strings
│   │   ├── InfoPlist.strings
│   │   ├── ListRowViewController.strings
│   │   └── Localizable.strings
│   ├── ro.lproj
│   │   ├── FMFNoFriendsViewController.strings
│   │   ├── FMFNoiCloudViewController.strings
│   │   ├── InfoPlist.strings
│   │   ├── ListRowViewController.strings
│   │   └── Localizable.strings
│   ├── ru.lproj
│   │   ├── FMFNoFriendsViewController.strings
│   │   ├── FMFNoiCloudViewController.strings
│   │   ├── InfoPlist.strings
│   │   ├── ListRowViewController.strings
│   │   └── Localizable.strings
│   ├── sk.lproj
│   │   ├── FMFNoFriendsViewController.strings
│   │   ├── FMFNoiCloudViewController.strings
│   │   ├── InfoPlist.strings
│   │   ├── ListRowViewController.strings
│   │   └── Localizable.strings
│   ├── sv.lproj
│   │   ├── FMFNoFriendsViewController.strings
│   │   ├── FMFNoiCloudViewController.strings
│   │   ├── InfoPlist.strings
│   │   ├── ListRowViewController.strings
│   │   └── Localizable.strings
│   ├── th.lproj
│   │   ├── FMFNoFriendsViewController.strings
│   │   ├── FMFNoiCloudViewController.strings
│   │   ├── InfoPlist.strings
│   │   ├── ListRowViewController.strings
│   │   └── Localizable.strings
│   ├── tr.lproj
│   │   ├── FMFNoFriendsViewController.strings
│   │   ├── FMFNoiCloudViewController.strings
│   │   ├── InfoPlist.strings
│   │   ├── ListRowViewController.strings
│   │   └── Localizable.strings
│   ├── uk.lproj
│   │   ├── FMFNoFriendsViewController.strings
│   │   ├── FMFNoiCloudViewController.strings
│   │   ├── InfoPlist.strings
│   │   ├── ListRowViewController.strings
│   │   └── Localizable.strings
│   ├── vi.lproj
│   │   ├── FMFNoFriendsViewController.strings
│   │   ├── FMFNoiCloudViewController.strings
│   │   ├── InfoPlist.strings
│   │   ├── ListRowViewController.strings
│   │   └── Localizable.strings
│   ├── zh_CN.lproj
│   │   ├── FMFNoFriendsViewController.strings
│   │   ├── FMFNoiCloudViewController.strings
│   │   ├── InfoPlist.strings
│   │   ├── ListRowViewController.strings
│   │   └── Localizable.strings
│   └── zh_TW.lproj
│       ├── FMFNoFriendsViewController.strings
│       ├── FMFNoiCloudViewController.strings
│       ├── InfoPlist.strings
│       ├── ListRowViewController.strings
│       └── Localizable.strings
├── _CodeSignature
│   └── CodeResources
└── version.plist
```

### Update 2

The OP tried the following command to reset the launch services database and this resolved the issue - `lsregister -kill -seed`

Comment: This results in an error dialog containing "Failed to find Widget /System/Library/Frameworks/NotificationCenter.framework/PlugIns/com.apple.ncplugin.FindMyFriends.appex". This error message is strange as the plugin is there. I confirmed it with `ls -ahl /System/Library/Frameworks/NotificationCenter.framework/PlugIns/`

Comment: Hmmm, right click the widget in Finder and click "Show Package Contents".  It should contain a directory called "Contents".  Open that directory and it should contain a tree of directories like the one I've added to the answer

Comment: Looks OK. It has "Contents" in there `_CodeSignature`, `Info.plist`, `MacOS`, `Resources`, `version.plist`.

Comment: Weird, if you log into another account on your Mac, even the guest one, does the same problem exist?  Maybe it's specific to your userid

Comment: Yes, it is specific to this userid. After your comments I investigated a bit more and I came up with the idea that the launch services database may be corrupted. I reset it using "lsregister -kill -seed" and it works now. Thank you so much. Bounty is yours!

Comment: Good find! I'll add that to the answer to help others in future

Comment: I think you need to click on the +50 button to actually award the bounty rather than just accept the answer :)

Comment: MacOS Catalina just removed the Widget from iOS and OSX. :( RIP FindMyFriends Widget.